# Increase Bootstrap components sizes (inputs, labels, fonts, buttons, etc..) at once

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a responsible site but as you can see by the pictures (http://postimg.org/image/xoq7eyg1b/), it's not totally mobile-friendly because the components are shown kind of small. 
To avoid the need to resize each one of them explicitly, is there any way to enlarge everything at once?

Code of the printed page:

```
<div class='row' id='content-wrapper'>
    <div class='col-xs-12'>
        <div class='page-header'>
            <h1 class='pull-left'><i class='icon-stethoscope'></i>&nbsp;Doenças Crônicas</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="divGrid">
    <div class='col-sm-12 col-md-3'>
        <div style="width:101% !important" class="box">
            <div class="box-header box-header-small dark-orange-background">
                <div class="title">
                    <div class="icon-search"></div>
                    Pesquisa
                </div>
                <div class='actions'>
                    <a class="btn box-collapse btn-xs btn-link" href="#"><i></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box-content">
                <form class="form form-horizontal" method="post" action="#" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" style="text-align: left;" for="nome">Nome</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input class="form-control input-sm" style="height:33px !important;font-size:medium !important" id="nome" placeholder="Ao menos 3 letras" type="text" data-bind="value: model.Nome" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" style="text-align: left;" for="Email">E-mail</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input class="form-control input-sm" style="height:33px !important;font-size:medium !important" id="Email" placeholder="Ao menos 3 letras" type="text" data-bind="value: model.Email" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" style="text-align: left;" for="Sexo">Sexo</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <select id="Sexo" class="form-control input-sm" style="height:33px !important;font-size:medium !important" data-bind="value: model.Sexo, ">
                                <option value="">-- Todos --</option>
                                <option value="M">Masculino</option>
                                <option value="F">Feminino</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" style="text-align: left;" for="IsMonitorado">Monitorado</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <select id="IsMonitorado" class="form-control input-sm" style="height:33px !important;font-size:medium !important" data-bind="value: model.IsMonitorado, ">
                                <option value="">-- Todos --</option>
                                <option value="1">Sim</option>
                                <option value="0">Não</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" style="text-align: left;" for="FaixaIdade">Faixa Idade</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <select id="FaixaIdade" class="form-control input-sm" style="height:33px !important;font-size:medium !important" data-bind="value: model.FaixaIdade, ">
                                <option value="">-- Todos --</option>
                                <option value="1">0 a 18 anos</option>
                                <option value="2">19 a 23 anos</option>
                                <option value="3">24 a 28 anos</option>
                                <option value="4">29 a 33 anos</option>
                                <option value="5">34 a 38 anos</option>
                                <option value="6">39 a 43 anos</option>
                                <option value="7">44 a 48 anos</option>
                                <option value="8">49 a 53 anos</option>
                                <option value="9">54 a 58 anos</option>
                                <option value="10">59 anos ou mais</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label " style="text-align: left;" for="situacao">Situação</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <select id="situacao" class="form-control input-sm" style="height:33px !important;font-size:medium !important" data-bind="value: model.StAtivo, ">
                                <option value="">-- Todos --</option>
                                <option value="1">Ativo</option>
                                <option value="0">Inativo</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-actions form-actions-padding-xs">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
                                <button class="btn btn-sm" type="button" data-bind="click: limpar">Limpar</button>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button" data-bind="click: submit"><i class="icon-search"></i>&nbsp;Pesquisar</button>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='col-sm-12 col-md-9'>
        <div style="width:101% !important" data-bind="kendoGrid: model.items"></div>
    </div>



</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="NovoPaciente" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header blue-background">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title text-white" id="myModalLabel"><i class="icon-user"></i>&nbsp;NOVO PACIENTE</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">


                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class='form-group'>
                                <label for='inputText'>Nome/Identificação*</label>
                                <input class='form-control' type='text' data-bind="value: model.Nome, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class='form-group'>
                                <label for='inputText'>Endereço*</label>
                                <textarea class='form-control' rows='2' data-bind="value: model.Endereco"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class='form-group'>
                                <label for='inputText'>Telefone</label>
                                <input class='form-control' type="text" data-bind="masked: model.Telefone, mask: '(99) 9999-9999'" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class='form-group'>
                                <label for='inputText'>Sexo*</label>
                                <select class="form-control" data-bind="options: model.ComboSexo, optionsText: 'Text', optionsValue: 'Value', optionsCaption: '-- Selecione --', value: model.Sexo, "></select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class='form-group'>
                                <label for='inputText'>Nascimento*</label>
                                <div class="form-group">

                                    <input class="form-control" id="txtDtNascimento" type="text" data-bind="value: model.DtNascimento, datepicker: model.DtNascimento, datepickerOptions: { altFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy' }  " />

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class='form-group'>
                                <label for='tipoDocumento'>Unidade*</label>
                                <select id="tipoDocumento" class="form-control" data-bind="click: function(e) { obterEquipesUnidade(this) }, options: model.ComboUnidade, optionsText: 'Text', optionsValue: 'Value', value: model.IdUnidade, optionsCaption: '-- Selecione --', "></select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class='form-group'>
                                <label for='inputText'>Equipe</label>
                                <select class="form-control" data-bind="options: model.comboEquipe, optionsText: 'Descricao', optionsValue: 'Id', optionsCaption: '-- Selecione --', value: model.IdEquipe, "></select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class='form-group'>
                                <label for='tipoDocumento'>Assinatura do TCLE</label>
                                <br />
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="Tcle" value="true" data-bind="checkedRadioToBool: model.Tcle" />
                                    Sim
                                </label>
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="Tcle" value="false" data-bind="checkedRadioToBool: model.Tcle" />
                                    Não
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class='form-group'>
                                <label for='inputText'>Altura</label>
                                <input class='form-control' type='text' id="Altura" data-bind="value: model.Altura, masked: model.Altura, mask: '0.00'">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class='form-group'>
                                <label for='inputText'>Chave de acesso</label>
                                <input class='form-control' type="text" data-bind="numeric: number, value: model.ChaveAcesso" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class='form-group'>
                                <label for='inputText'>E-mail<span data-bind="text: model.Obrigatorio"></span></label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="email" data-bind="value: model.Email" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class='form-group'>
                                <label for='inputText'>Outras Informações</label>
                                <textarea class='form-control' rows='2' data-bind="value: model.Observacao"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class='form-group'>
                                <label for='inputText'>Senha<span data-bind="text: model.Obrigatorio"></span> </label>
                                <input type="password" class='form-control' data-bind="value: model.Senha" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class='form-group'>
                                <label for='inputText'>Confirmação<span data-bind="text: model.Obrigatorio"></span> </label>
                                <input type="password" class='form-control' data-bind="value: model.ConfirmSenha" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click: cancel">Fechar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: save">Salvar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try increasing the `font-size` in the `<body>`.

```
@media screen (max-device-width:$mobile-breakpoint) {
    body {
        font-size:120%;
    }
}
```

Also, you could use `em` units instead of pixels (I don't know if you do because you didn't post your CSS). These `em` units are always relative to the `font-size` set on the `<body>` tag. You can use media queries to increase or decrease the size of one `em` unit depending on the viewport.

Good `em` reference: https://css-tricks.com/css-font-size/

Answer (score 1):

In Bootstrap, the font sizes are given in `em` units, so you can set a baseline font size in your CSS, and all of the font should scale accordingly.

1. Create a new CSS page, so you're not editing bootstrap.css directly.
   Call it custom.css. It should contain:

   `html { font-size: 16px; }`
2. Add a reference to custom.css below the references to bootstrap, something like this (you don't show that part of your code so I'm just guessing here):

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/css/bootstrap.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/css/bootstrap-theme.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/css/custom.css"/>`

The code in custom.css should overwrite whatever baseline font gets set initially. If setting the css for `html` doesn't work, try `body`.

Comment: Doing like this, font sizes will be scaled only in mobile devices? It must not change if I'm browsing on desktops.